# How to check java version on multiple servers?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, java, version

I have 100 servers and i need to login to them with ssh from central server using script: i tried below with this i should get the version redirected to the file which will be stored at central server.

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD='java -version'
while read line
do
    ssh -n user@"$line" $CMD >> /pathforoutputfile/outputjava.txt

done < /pathforhosts/hosts.txt
```

But I am not getting output generated in file `/pathforoutputfile/outputjava.txt`

Comment: you could use `ansible` for server orchestration. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388361/ansible-command-to-check-the-java-version-in-different-servers

Comment: Script looks fine, try running it with `set -x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command does in fact write to stderr.

```
ron@haggis:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
ron@haggis:~$ 
ron@haggis:~$ java -version 2> foo.txt
ron@haggis:~$ cat foo.txt
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Thus, you should redirect using `2>>` instead of `>>` in

```
ssh -n sgarole@"$line" $CMD >> /pathforoutputfile/outputjava.txt
```

One other thing I noticed is that you don't seem to be mentioning the remote host names in `/pathforoutputfile/outputjava.txt`.

Comment: Doing an ordinary `>` redirect after `done` removes the need to manually delete the output file each time the script is being rerun: `...; done <inputfile >outputfile`  And the host could simply be outputted with `printf '%s\n' "$line"` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks @fabby redirecting output using 2>> helped.

Comment: @SantoshGarole Don't thank me: I just edited RonJohn's original answer.  (The best way of thanking is to upvote the answer once you get enough reputation)  **;-)**